# How to create New Documents in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, google-drive-api

What are the urls to create new documents in google docs or google drive?
When Google Drive was launch some of the links that can be found on some blogs on the net are now invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the links that I've tested which works (As of June 1, 2012)

Create New Google Documents
https://docs.google.com/DocAction?action=newdoc

Create New Spreadsheet
http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?new

Create New Presentation
https://docs.google.com/DocAction?action=new_presentation

Create New Drawing
https://docs.google.com/drawings/create?hl=en

Comment: Update Jan 2017: spreadsheet and presentation worked. Doc and Drawing did not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with Google Docs programaticaly, you should use the [GData API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/). Google provides clients in a number of different languages.

Comment: Yes, that can be done via GData API. I was just trying to make some desktop shortcuts, and these urls can be used for that. I've just shared the urls so if anyone would need them later on.